# jQuery: best way to get the index of an element in an event handler

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to retrieve the index of an element in an event handler:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>

$("ul li").click(function() {
  // what is the index of the list item that was clicked?
});
```

In other words, if I click the 'c' item, is there a best practice for getting the index of 2 from within the event handler?

I know I can determine the element's position by looking at its parent, but I don't know if there is a better or more concise way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call [`$(this).index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index).

Comment: This did not work for me in a similar context. The index was always 0. Perhaps because my selector was `$(".foo")` and not scoped like `$(".container .foo")`? Adam's solution of `$(".foo").index(this)` did work.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is an "index" method for this.

So you could write:

```
$("#ul_id li").click(function() {
  var index = $("#ul_id li").index(this);
});
```

Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: That will give the index in the complete set of `<li>`s, including earlier `<ul>`s.

Comment: No, I tried it. This works fine. In fact, I took it straight from the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/index/#entry-examples

Comment: It will only work fine in the first `<ul>` in the page.  `$("ul li")` selects _every_ `<li>`, regardless of parent.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I purposely used a simplistic css selector because his example code was also simplistic. Obviously, in a real-world application, you'd want to use a selector with an ID or class. But besides using this simple selector, I actually prefer this index() syntax because it is more clear to another developer what is happening. "Within the selector, get the index of this element"

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of previous list items.

```
$(this).prevAll("li").size();
```

Edited vie Felix.

Comment: `prev` only selects the previous sibling. You want `prevAll`.

Comment: @felix...You're right. I was doing this from memory. I'll edit