# How can I retrieve the child position of a list item during a jQuery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I retrieve the child position of a list item during a jQuery click event?

```
ul
    li
    li
    li

$('li').click(//pass index of li into function)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `nth-child`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: best way to get the index of an element in an event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437045/jquery-best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-event-handler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is find out which `li` was clicked in the alert:

```
$('li').click(
    function(){
        alert($(this).index());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g3JS5/).

Comment: You're welcome! But, is that all you need this to do? Where does the `nth-child()` come into it?

Comment: Sorry I was just using that as a bad representation for its index. Wanting to solve for n but in that context it doesn't make sense.