# How to find Nth Element , when a click is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
```

Is there any way to identify that when a mouse is clicked at random.

Is there anyway to get nth element of the selected through mouse ?

edit: when we click over a paragraph, i am using jquery

Comment: what do you mean by *selected through mouse?*

Comment: You mean, how to find the position of the element that was clicked?

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah i am using jquery, yes when clicked through mouse

Comment: What is `n` in this case? How is the nth element related to the clicked element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: best way to get the index of an element in an event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437045/jquery-best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-event-handler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This logs the index of the paragraph that was clicked.

```
var $elems = $('p');
$elems.on('click', function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    console.log("Element with index: " + indexOfElem + " was clicked.");
});
```

Something like this?

Comment: What do you expect this will do?

Comment: "If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**." -- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Perhaps the previous behavior was the desired one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `index` function in jQuery returns the position of an element within the jQuery object. To find the position of the clicked element within some list:

```
var $elems = $("#context > p");
$elems.on("click", function() {
  var i = $elems.index(this);
  console.log(i); // use the index
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    $('p').click(function () {

    alert($('p').index(this));
    });
```

Comment: No need to jquerify `this`.